# How does `first-child` work with arbitrary variants in tailwind css?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've been trying to make sense of the `first-child` pseudo selector and [this toy example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/fuYdQ4rwnh) has me really confused..

```
<div class="[&:first-child]:text-red-500">
  <ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>def</li>
    <li>ghi</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="[&:first-child]:text-blue-500">
    <li>jkl</li>
    <li>mno</li>
    <li>pqr</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

#### My expectation

I *thought* that `[&:first-child]:text-red-500` meant

> turn the text red, for the first child of *this element* (`&`)

but clearly that's not the case. What's really going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *thought* that `[&:first-child]:text-red-500` meant

> turn the text red, for the first child of *this element* (`&`)

That's incorrect. It means

> turn the text red, if this element is the first child of its parent.

What you want is `[&>:first-child]:text-red-500`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! Btw, I don't _want_ anything in particular. I'm merely playing around with the selector, trying to wrap my head around it :)